# How To Find Name Property Of Parent Element When ContextMenu MenuItem Is Clicked

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, contextmenu, menuitem

I have the following code which creates a new Button with a ContextMenu with a single MenuItem called "Remove".

My question is...in the removeItem_Click EventHandler, how do I find out the Name property of the Button that contained this ContextMenu MenuItem?

```
private Button CreateRdpConnectionButton(string content, string name)
{
    var newButton = new Button();            
    newButton.Content = content;
    newButton.Name = name;
    newButton.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;

    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
    item.Header = "Remove";
    item.Click += removeItem_Click;
    menu.Items.Add(item);

    newButton.ContextMenu = menu;
}

void removeItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Find name of Button that contained this item
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store that info in the `item.Tag` when you create it, then in the handler you can just cast the `sender` (to `MenuItem`) and retrieve it again.

Comment: using tag to store information you already have in MenuItem.Parent is not a good solution

Comment: @Beatles1692: The question was how to *"find out the Name property of the Button that contained this ContextMenu MenuItem"*, you will ***not*** get this from `MenuItem.Parent`.

Comment: @Beatles1692: And one little change in the menu hierarchy and your code blows up, *really* great idea...

Answer (score 3):

You could also directly access the parents:

```
void removeItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Find name of Button that contained this item
    MenuItem    menuItem      = (MenuItem)sender;
    ContextMenu contextMenu   = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;
    Button      button        = (Button)contextMenu.PlacementTarget;

    string buttonName = button.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use (MenuItem)sender to access your menu item

Answer (score 0):

Store data as `<Button Tag=""/>` and retrieve the tag as `(sender as Button).Tag`

Comment: Pretty much identical to the accepted answer and the comments that follow.